# Extract a substring from a string that its length is unknown in Java

Tags: java, string

I need to extract a substring from a string, the length of the string is unknown.
For example "435323 London KingRoad" and I need to extract London and Kingroad (each of them separately)
How can I do it?

Comment: "the length of the string is unknown" - but you can always find the length of the original string, with the `length()` method. Are you really just looking for the `split()` method though?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java?r=SearchResults&s=1|443.4187

Comment: use split inside of substring

Comment: Yes, the link to the question you sent me helped me a lot, thank u so much!

Answer (score 0):

If every string is in this format, you might as well just write

```
String[] words = string.split(" ");
return new CityAndRoad(words[1], words[2]);
```

or return them in whatever other format is appropriate.